# Multilingual in grails view

Tags: grails, internationalization

i'm working in Multilingual grails application (English and arbaic) , i want when the user chooses Arabic language the view's labels will be on the right side of the page and in English on the left side , how this can be achieved ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use internationalization in grails through messages.properties file, you can define message signature in files and and they can be accessed through ?lang=es on the URL, you may need to have two files one for english and another for Arabic.

for example define in the messages.properties:

```
vendor.link.dashboardLink = Vendor Dashboard
```

and on the GSP page you can access it like:

```
<g:message code="vendor.link.dashboardLink" />
```

you can find more about internalization at grails doc have a look at http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

If the views have differences beyond simple string substitution, I would recommend using a different set of views based on locale:

Example controller code:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU

class ExampleController {
    final static String englishLanguageCode = new Locale('en').getLanguage()
    final static String arabicLanguageCode = new Locale('ar').getLanguage()

    def differentViews() {
        def currentLocale = RCU.getLocale(request)

        switch(currentLocale.language) {
            case englishLanguageCode:
                render view: 'englishView'
                break
            case arabicLanguageCode:
                render view: 'arabicView'
                break
            default:
                // pick a default view or error page, etc.
        }
    }
}
```